# How to override CompositeView render method?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, marionette

I need to render only first element of fetched collection.

```
ItemView = Backbone.Marionette.ItemView.extend({
    template:  "#item"
});

ItemsEmptyView = Backbone.Marionette.ItemView.extend({
    template: "#items_empty"
});

ItemsView = Backbone.Marionette.CompositeView.extend({
    template: "#items",
    itemView: ItemView,
    emptyView: ItemEmptyView
});
```

How can I accomplish that? I've tried to override `render()` method, or `onBeforeRender()` nothing helps.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you really need to do this, use `appendHtml()`.

```
appendHtml: function(collectionView, itemView, index){
    if ( index === 0 )
        collectionView.$el.append(itemView.el);
}
```

https://github.com/marionettejs/backbone.marionette/blob/master/docs/marionette.compositeview.md#compositeviews-appendhtml

Answer (score 1):

The easiest is to create a new collection instance containing only the first model, and pass that to the composite view. Of course, this is assuming you can't simply use an item view.